# Hide an option in a dropdown menu, when a specific option has been selected in another menu

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, drop-down-menu, mysqli

I'm stuck right now on the following problem:
I have 2 dropdown menus next to each other, that both offer the same options to choose from (users can choose their travel route by choosing their point of departure and their destination).

The items on these dropdown menus are taken from a table in my database.
I want to achieve the following:

Locations "A", "B" and "C" are choosable as start or destination. When a user chooses "B" as point of departure (in the 1st dropdown menu), this option should not be shown anymore in the 2nd dropdown menu (destination). (EDIT: But it should reappear, when another option is selected in the 1st dropdown)
Same with "A" and "C" of course.

The code I use right now to fill the dropdown menus is:

```
<select name="anfang">
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM orte";
$result = mysqli_query($dblogin,$sql); 

while($zeilestart=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
include("includes/database.php");

$ortname=$zeilestart['name'];
$ortkurz=$zeilestart['kurz'];

echo "<option value=\"$ortkurz\">";
echo $ortname; 
echo "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

This is the code for the 1st dropdown menu (start), the code for the 2nd menu is pretty much the same.

I assume that some JavaScript-code can solve my problem, but I don't really know how to do it... Can anyone help me? :)

Thanks and kind regards

weheri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should be easy to understand - it basically queries the DOM for the first dropdown list's select element and the second dropdown lists' options elements. It attaches an event handler to the `onchange` event of the first select, so that whenever its value changes, the handler function is called to check all the options on the second select against the selected value. If the value matches, it sets a `disabled` attribute on the option, otherwise if the option has a `disabled` attribute (from a previous selection), it removes it.

You can add this to your page before the closing `body` tag, changing `secondSelect` to the name of your second dropdown.

```
<script>
    var select1 = document.querySelector('select[name="anfang"]'),
        secondList= document.querySelectorAll('select[name="secondSelect"] option');
    select1.onchange = function(){
        var selected = this.value;
        for(var i=0;i<secondList.length;i++){
             if(secondList[i].value==selected)
                secondList[i].setAttribute('disabled',true);
             else if(secondList[i].getAttribute('disabled'))
                secondList[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you would like to hide the element altogether (instead of disabling it), you can to use the `style` attribute instead of `disabled`:

```
<script>
    var select1 = document.querySelector('select[name="anfang"]'),
        secondList= document.querySelectorAll('select[name="secondSelect"] option');
    select1.onchange = function(){
        var selected = this.value;
        for(var i=0;i<secondList.length;i++){
             if(secondList[i].value==selected)
                secondList[i].style.display = "none";
             else if(secondList[i].style.display == "none")
                secondList[i].removeAttribute('style'); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work unfortunately...
I made a simpler version here with your code: http://team3.digital-cultures.net/start.php
Still all options choosable in the 2nd menu :/

Comment: Sorry just noticed a small error in my _document.querySelectorAll_ call, I wrote "options" instead of "option" (and forgot to close a bracket) - try again, should work.

Comment: Tried that (both the code to disable and to hide it), but still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Both seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/dutz2s1b/, http://jsfiddle.net/dutz2s1b/1/

Comment: Weird, copied the code from the fiddle and suddenly it work! Awesome, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Might have been the case of the missing closing bracket :). That's why fiddles help a lot. Do accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing the code when I saw this already have been answered, but here is my contribution (full code example, using a php array to get the data from instead of a mysqli object/array)

http://pastebin.com/0J31FK15

Comment: Ah I don't think they want to remove the element, just disable it. A user might change the selected value after selecting it once. In any case there should be an option to bring it back, right?

Comment: The op wrote "this option should not be shown anymore", by disabling it, it will still be visible. If that is the case, then you could store all values in an object/array or just the removed value in a string, and if the user should go back then you just add the missing value or you can re-create the entire select element.

Comment: You're right, wasn't stated clearly... But Sidd is right, I edited my post accordingly :) Thanks though!